# Does the Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro support the Surface Pro 3 touch pen?

Tags: lenovo-laptop, microsoft-surface-pro

Like the title is saying... Does the Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro support the Surface Pro 3 touch pen?

I ask the question because it seems that we can now buy the Surface Pro 3 pen as mentioned on [WinBeta Site - Microsoft sells Surface 3 pen for 50$](http://www.winbeta.org/news/microsoft-sells-unbundled-surface-3-pen-50-microsoft-store).

The only thing that I know is that the Yoga 2 Pro does not have a digitizer, hence the Surface 1-2 pen would not work but I am not sure about the Surface Pro 3?

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost 100% certain it won't since the Surface Pro 3 pen is non-standard. Produced by an Israeli company that Microsoft have now brought out.

The Thinkpad Yoga at least had a more standard Wacom interface and you can use some (but not all) Wacom pens.